# WPF: Bezier curve using DrawingContext

Tags: wpf, drawing, bezier, drawingcontext

I want to draw a bezier curve using DrawingContext class as follows:

```
var pathFigure = new PathFigure();
pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(Width - 15, line.Position + line.Height);

pathFigure.Segments.Add(new BezierSegment(new Point(Width - 7.5, line.Position + line.Height - 20),new Point(Width, line.Position + line.Height + 20), new Point(Width + 7.5, line.Position + line.Height), false));
pathFigure.IsClosed = false;

var path = new PathGeometry();
path.Figures.Add(pathFigure);

drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Black, _blackPen, path);
```

My _blackPen is initialized as follows:

```
 _blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
```

But I get this result:

[image]

But what I want is something like what is shown in [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Windows-Presentation-Foundation/CubicBezierCurvewithBezierSegment.htm).

So what am I missing?

EDIT:

When I set `pathFigure.IsFilled = false;` the path disappears:

[image]

The same goes for `drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, _blackPen, path);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not fill the geometry.

Either use a `null` Brush

```
drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, _blackPen, path);
```

or set

```
pathFigure.IsFilled = false;
```

---

You also need to set the `IsStroked` property of the BezierSegment to `true`:

```
pathFigure.Segments.Add(
    new BezierSegment(
        new Point(Width - 7.5, line.Position + line.Height - 20),
        new Point(Width, line.Position + line.Height + 20),
        new Point(Width + 7.5, line.Position + line.Height),
        true)); // here
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the path disappears when I don't fill it. I added this point to the question.

Comment: You have accidentially set `IsStroked` to false. See the edit.